# I couldnt understand the specific part of a code

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

The goal of this exercise is to generate a chart as in this page: (http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2012/president/us/general_election_romney_vs_obama-1171.html)

The data used to generate plots like this are stored as XML pages, with URLs like:
http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/[id].xml
Here, [id] is a unique integer, found at the end of the URL of the page that displays the graph. The id for the Obama-Romney race is 1171:

```
import re 

def get_poll_xml(poll_id):
    url ="http://charts.realclearpolitics.com/charts/%i.xml" %int(poll_id)
    return requests.get(url).text

def _strip(s): # function to remove characters
    return re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s)

def plot_colors(xml):
    '''
    Given an XML document like the link above, returns a python dictionary
    that maps a graph title to a graph color.

    Both the title and color are parsed from attributes of the <graph> tag:
    <graph title="the title", color="#ff0000"> -> {'the title': '#ff0000'}
   '''
    dom = web.Element(xml)
    result = {}
    for graph in dom.by_tag('graph'):
        title = _strip(graph.attributes['title'])
        result[title] = graph.attributes['color']
    return result

def rcp_poll_data(xml):
    """ 
     A pandas DataFrame with the following columns:
    date: The date for each entry
    title_n: The data value for the gid=n graph 

    This DataFrame should be sorted by date

    Example
     -------
     Consider the following simple xml page:

   <chart>
   <series>
   <value xid="0">1/27/2009</value>
   <value xid="1">1/28/2009</value>
   </series>
  <graphs>
  <graph gid="1" color="#000000" balloon_color="#000000" title="Approve">
  <value xid="0">63.3</value>
  <value xid="1">63.3</value>
  </graph>
  <graph gid="2" color="#FF0000" balloon_color="#FF0000" title="Disapprove">
  <value xid="0">20.0</value>
  <value xid="1">20.0</value>
  </graph>
  </graphs>
  </chart>

  Given this string, rcp_poll_data should return
  result = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['1/27/2009', '1/28/2009']), 
                       'Approve': [63.3, 63.3], 'Disapprove': [20.0, 20.0]})
  """
    dom = web.Element(xml)
    result = {}        

    dates = dom.by_tag('series')[0]    
    dates = {n.attributes['xid']: str(n.content) for n in dates.by_tag('value')}

    keys = dates.keys()
    result['date'] = pd.to_datetime([dates[k] for k in keys]) 

    for graph in dom.by_tag('graph'):
        name = graph.attributes['title']
        data = {n.attributes['xid']: float(n.content) if n.content else np.nan for n   in graph.by_tag('value') }
        keyl = data.keys()    
        result[name] = [data[k]for k in keyl]

    result = pd.DataFrame(result)   
    result = result.sort(columns=['date'])

    return result

def poll_plot(poll_id):
    xml = get_poll_xml(poll_id)
    data = rcp_poll_data(xml)
    colors = plot_colors(xml)

    #remove characters like apostrophes
    data = data.rename(columns = {c: _strip(c) for c in data.columns})

    #normalize poll numbers so they add to 100%    
    norm = data[colors.keys()].sum(axis=1) / 100    
    for c in colors.keys():
        data[c] /= norm

    for label, color in colors.items():
        plt.plot(data.date, data[label], color=color, label=label)        

    plt.xticks(rotation=70)
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel("Normalized Poll Percentage")

poll_plot(1044)
plt.title("Obama Job Approval")
```

In the above mentioned code, I couldnt understand the following part, can some one explain me. I am completely lost.

```
data = data.rename(columns = {c: _strip(c) for c in data.columns})

#normalize poll numbers so they add to 100%    
norm = data[colors.keys()].sum(axis=1) / 100    
for c in colors.keys():
    data[c] /= norm

for label, color in colors.items():
    plt.plot(data.date, data[label], color=color, label=label)
```

Comment: I think that someone else worked on it before. Perhaps this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343016/parse-through-an-xml-in-python

Comment: No but it doesnt solve my problem. I couldnt understand a certain part of my code. But the parsing example is completly different

Comment: "Can you explain this code for me please" doesn't make a good SO question. We need to hear why you don't understand it, specifically what you don't understand, and perhaps more importantly why you *have* all this code that you don't understand. :) I mean, the code you're having trouble with doesn't look any more complicated to me than the rest that you had no problem with...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know I am asking stupid questions, but please bear me I am a beginner. I am determined to teach myself python. As I want to get into datascience.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: my specific query is in this part  ->for c in colors.keys():
        data[c] /= norm, what is data[c] /= norm. Please explain

Answer (score 1):

You said in comments that you want to know what means `/=`. It is called **Augmented Assignement** and is defined in [PEP 203](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/).

You have an *int* var and want to sum a value to it

```
n = 1
n = n + 1
print n
2
```

Here is an optimized way to do it

```
n = 1
n += 1
```

It is very useful to use in loops

```
n = 1
while n < 10:
    n += 1

print n
10
```

So with `/=` you're using **div** operator instead **add**

```
n = 4
n /= 2
print n
2

n = 10
while n > 2:
    n /= 2

print n
2
```

For more info about Augmented Assignement take a look at [Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment) entry.

Comment: Got it :). could you also explain. headers = table.by_tag('th') labels = [str(t.content).split('(')[0].strip() for t in headers[3:-1]]... I know what is meant by split and strip. But what deos split('(')[0] means?? –

Comment: Try this on console `print '123(456(789'.split('(')[0]` and you'll understand.

Comment: Got it. split function returns a list and split[0] returns the first element in the list.

Comment: You could elect one of answers as valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what the syntax `data[c] /= norm` means, it is similar to the more common `+=` operator. It takes the left side of the left side of the assignment and assigns it that left side's value divided by the right sides value. It is equivalent to `data[c] = data[c]/norm`. For example

```
x = 6.0
x /= 2.0
```

Now `x` will have a value of `3.0`

Please try to be more clear in what exactly you are asking in your question, and calling out the particular part of the code you do not understand.

Comment: @JacobBower- I am pretty new to stack over flow. Thanks for the answer. could you also explain. headers = table.by_tag('th')
    labels = [str(t.content).split('(')[0].strip() for t in headers[3:-1]]... I know what is meant by split and strip. But what deos split('(')[0] means??